# How to show a loading image when opening a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am opening my user control in an iframe. Because of this, my user control is taking time to be displayed inside an iframe. I thought of showing a **"Loading. Please wait.."** image until my user control is loaded in the iframe. My changes are as below:

**.js**

```
var originalURL = pageURL + "/MDMDataHub/AddAliasPage.aspx?SOURCE_HQ_REF=" + sourceHQRef + "&HQ_SOURCE_NAME=" + sourceName + "&BUSINESS_RID=" + rGroupId;
                                var width = $(this).attr('data-width') || 595;
                                $('#aliasPopUpHeader').find('h4').remove();
                                $('#aliasPopUpHeader').append('  <h4 class="modal-title" >  ' + "Add Parent Alias " + ' confirmation !</h4>');
                                $("#addAliasPopUp").dialog({
                                    autoOpen: true,
                                    width: width,
                                    resizable: true,
                                    draggable: true,
                                    modal: true,                                        
                                    show: { effect: 'blind' },
                                }).find('iframe').attr("src", originalURL);
```

**aspx page**

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="addAliasPopUp" style="display: none">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" id="aliasPopUpHeader">
            <button type="button" class="close closePopup closePopAlias">
                <span>&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="AddAliasConfirmPopUP">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" style="height:600px;width:100%"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="aliasClosePopUp" class="btn btn-cancel closePopup closePopAlias">
                Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now on the click event of a button, I am opening the dialog(mentioned in the jquery). I now, want to show a gif image till my user control is loaded in the iframe. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

To show a gif image while your page is getting loaded.
1. Add an hidden div on your page `<div id="preloader"></div>`
2. Add following CSS :

```
    div#preloader { 
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 999; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: visible; 
    background-image: url('../images/please_wait_animation.gif'); 
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); 
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    }
```

3. Then display it using `$('#preloader').show();` when processing is going on.
4. Lastly, hide the div using `$('#preloader').hide();` when the page gets loaded.